# How to define $\pi$ from geometry to the limit of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, pi

There are several definitions of $\pi$ based on the limit of some sequences or series. (Maybe) The most famous example is the solution of the Basel problem:

$$\pi = \sqrt{6 \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}}.$$

Anyway, even though I've found several of these sequences, none of them seems to be derived by using a **constructive geometric approach.**

What I mean? For instance, let's consider a unit circle and the regular polyhedra inscribed with $m>2$ sides. Let $s_m$ the side length of the $m$-th polyhedron. Then, we can define $\pi$ as follows:

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{m \to +\infty} m\cdot s_m.$$

I've tried to find out the expression of $s_m$, but I need to define it by using $\pi$ itself, i.e.

$$s_m = \frac{2}{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)}.$$

So it seems that, in order to evaluate $\pi$, one needs to use $\pi$ itself!!!

---

Summing up, is there any sequence/series based on simple geometric arguments that can be used to define $\pi$?

Comment: There are various ways to define and to compute $\pi$ without landing in a logical circle.

Comment: @Peter I'm sure there are. But unfortunately I was not able to find them, and that's way I've asked this question. Can you kindly share some of these ways?

Comment: A sequence already very fast converging to $\pi$ is $x_0=3$ , $x_{n+1}=x_n+\sin(x_n)$. Geometrically, $\pi$ is usually defined to be the ratio between circumference and diameter of a circle.

Comment: This is similar to [Viète's formula for pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula)

Comment: The Basel problem does actually have somewhat of a geometric interpretation.  3Blue1Brown has an excellent [video](https://youtu.be/d-o3eB9sfls) on the subject, as well as a [video](https://youtu.be/8GPy_UMV-08) on a geometric proof of the Wallis product.

Comment: Don't let you fool , do not watch any math videos. I looked many , really many , for the sake of curiousity. It is not worth the time ! Read pdf- and wikipedia-articles , this is much better to make progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try to find a recursive relation between $s_{2^{n+1}}$ and $s_{2^n}$

Answer (score 0):

$\Pi_{k=0}^3(i+k)$ where $i^2=-1$ arguably does it in disguise.

This is $i(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)=(-1+i)(5+5i)=-10=10e^{i\pi/2}$

$(i+k)=\sqrt{k^2+1}e^{i\arctan(1/k)}$

You can think of $i$ as a vertical line of unit length starting at the origin. Multiplication by the subsequent terms extends the length of the line and rotates it a bit.

This all implies $\arctan{1/0}+\arctan{1}+\arctan{2}+\arctan{3}$ is a multiple of $\pi/2$. So the some of terms with a geometric meaning not explicitly mentioning $\pi$ add it to a rational multiple of $\pi$.